# Limit Exceeded: Email Recipients Per Message. but only 67 recipients?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, quota

I keep getting Limit Exceeded: Email Recipients Per Message. when trying to use the forward command in my google script.  I'm forwarding a message with 67 people BCCed and one person CCed, to field empty.  Why is this occuring?  It's the first email I'm sending during the day, and from everything I've read about the limits, this should be working.  Thanks!

(The BCC field is imported from a google drive spreadsheet with a comma delimited BCC forward list.)

Comment: Is the script for regular ol' Gmail or for the Google App Engine?

Comment: I don't know I'm new to this- I have the script attached to the spreadsheet, so it doesn't show up as it's own icon in the google drive.  I've been editing it by going to the spreadsheet>tools>script editor.  I took out several emails from the BCC field and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

In Apps Script, there are [a set of quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) in place that are meant to prevent abuse of the services.  You are running into one of these, which says that any email sent through Apps Script can have at most 50 recipients.

You can still accomplish what you are trying to do by either:

1. Breaking the recipient list into more than one set and sending out multiple emails (be careful that you don't exceed the Email recipients per day quota), or
2. Adding your recipients to a mailing list and sending a single email to the list instead.

If you frequently need to update the same set of individuals, #2 might be your best option. otherwise just divide up the work.

Comment: For documentation: Solution #2 is not a solution because you have to get all email included in a mailing list. Apps Script don't accept to send an email with only the name of the mailing list